# Python Regex: force greedy match using alternation

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex of the form:

```
a(bc|de|def)g?
```

On the string `adefg` this pattern is matching only up to "ade" and it is clearly quitting on the first match in the alternation group.  Removing the `?` option from the "g" token allows the pattern to match the entire string.  This makes sense since the "?" is non-greedy.  [EDIT: I have been corrected, the "?" **is** greedy, which just seems to add to my confusion.  It seemed to me that if the "?" were non-greedy, this was allowing the pattern to quit early when a larger match was available.]

I would like to avoid rearranging the order of the strings in the alternation, and I can solve the problem as is by appending (\b|$) to the pattern, but now I am really curious to know if there are other solutions

For instance, is there any way to make the "?" greedy or to force the alternation not to quit on the first match?

Comment: Yeah. At the moment, the strings in the alternation are being appended from another source and I would like to avoid messing with them.

Comment: @Schemer suitable question for codereview.

Comment: Why do you say Python's `?` is non-greedy? The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) say it is.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Thanks. I haven't kept up with proliferation of Stack Exchanges. :-)

Comment: @RayToal: My mistake. Then I really do not understand why removing that quantifier allows the pattern to match the entire string. That would seem to characterize the difference between greedy and non-greedy.

Comment: No worries, but you are right about it stopping on `ade`. It tries alternatives left to right. And `de` is the only match within the parens. `a(bc|def?)g?` would get it for you (as you probably know). When you remove the quantifier, you are forcing all alternatives to be tried because you are saying you _must_ match the `g`, and the only way this can be done is to get to the alternative with the `f`.

Comment: @RayToal: I thought the engine might explore all possibilities for getting to the end of the pattern in order to match as much as possible. Now that I am thinking about it though, I suspect the behaviour I was expecting to see in this case would lead to some mad recursion.

Comment: I am trully frustrated with re library after decades working with js and php who has GREEDY by default, try \d+ or d{3, } to match 09829408 it stops as quick or short match... hating this lazy behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You can't make the `|` not match its constituents left to right, because matching left to right is its [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) behavior.  Even if you could make the `?` "greedy", it wouldn't work, because the regex matches from beginning to end, so the greediness of the `?` couldn't have an effect until after the alternation had already matched.

Greediness doesn't make the regex engine go back to find a "better way" to match; it will match the first way it can.  It will only make use of the `g?` if it has to do so in order for the entire match to succeed, and it won't have to if it can just ignore it and stick with what it matched in the alternation.  In other words, once it matches "ade", it can succeed and stop (because it doesn't *need* to match the "g", since it's optional).  It therefore doesn't even consider the other parts of the alternation, since it can find a way to make it work using the first one.  A greedy `?` doesn't make it go back and retry other things it already matched unless it needs to for the entire match to succeed.

If you are using an alternation where some alternants are substrings of others, you should put them in order so the longest ones come first.

Another possibility is to add a `$` to the end of your regex.  This will force it to go all the way to the end of the string, so it *will* backtrack and try the other alternatives, because now "ade" won't be a match (since it doesn't match the `$`).  However, this will only work if you really do want to match the whole string.

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot of sense except that none of the alternants is actually consuming the "g".

Comment: Yes. I noted in the OP that appending (\b|$) solved the problem "as is", i.e., on the existing strings.

Comment: However, sorting the alternants in descending order does seem like a bullet-proof solution. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can usually use a negative lookahead, but I don't know the capabilities of Python's regex engine.

```
a(bc|de(?!f)|def)g?
```

[check here](https://regex101.com/r/qPZm8h/1)

Answer (score -1):

An obvious way to refactor this expression would be to "unroll" the optional part:

```
a(bc|de|def)g|a(bc|de|def)
```

or

```
(a(bc|de|def))g|\1
```

to avoid the repetition.

Comment: Actually, this suffers from the same problem of "short-circuiting" whenever the "g" token is missing but I still need to match "adef".

Comment: @Schemer: as you've been already told, this is not possible. I was answering your question how to make `?` "greedy" in your pattern.